# unity load sprit to gameobject from asset folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity. i have a simple sprite in this address:

```
Assets <- (Folder)
|
 - Block <- (Block is a PNG file that dragged to unity project widget)
```

I want to add my "Block" sprite dinamically to my "Scene" or inside my "Main Camera" game object.
I used this code to load block as Sprite:

```
Sprite block = Resources.Load<Sprite>( "Block" );
GameObject obj = new GameObject ("B1");
SpriteRenderer renderer = obj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = block;
obj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().flipX = true;
```

I can see "B1" game object created in my scene and have no error in my console, **but i cannot see the sprite** on my scene.

[image]

Note: Unity: 5.6.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work for you because it would need to be placed inside a folder called `Resources` like `Assets/Resources/Block.png`

---

#### However: [Don't use `Resources`](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) at all!

Rather simply leave your file as it is and drag it into the `Sprite` field in the Inspector. If you really need to do it on runtime then make sure the component executing your code has according field like e.g.

```c#
// Drag the sprite from the Assets here via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Sprite block;

private void YourMethod()
{
    var renderer = new GameObject ("B1").AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    renderer.sprite = block;
    renderer.flipX = true;
}
```

---

Also if you are new to Unity you shouldn't start with a legacy version. Use either the latest stable version `2019.3.4f1` or go for the Long Term Supported `2018.4 LTS` (though there soon will be the new LTS version `2019.4`)

Comment: @Shamshirsaz.Navid Gladd to help! As said **don't use it**! I really recommend the second solution - see the link

Comment: I checked it thanks :) but another concern; if i still use unity 5 for an android game, can i migrate later to 2019 edition ?

Comment: @Shamshirsaz.Navid unlikely without any problems .. a lot changed meanwhile!